# How can i resolve a problem with await in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to do a music bot for discord and I follow a tutorial for this.
But, when I run show this error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"
This is the code:

```
    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
const song = {
  title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
  url: songInfo.voiceDetails.video_url,
};
```

I can't understand what I have to change to works.

Comment: The error says "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function". So when you do `await ytdl.getInfo(args[1])`, it's probably outside of an async function. Can you include the full function that the code is in?

Answer (score 2):

`await` is waiting for the response of an asynchronous call before continuing the code.

However in JS you cannot "block the main thread", which is why you have to use an `async`function

If your code is already in a function just put the keyword `async` in front of it.

An other solution is to encapsulate your code into a funciton thas is called immediatly ie

```js
(async () =>  {
   const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
   const song = {
     title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
     url: songInfo.voiceDetails.video_url,
   };
})();
```

A 3rd solution is to drop the `await` keyword and work with promises

```js
  ytdl.getInfo(args[1]).then(songInfo => {
     const song = {
       title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
       url: songInfo.voiceDetails.video_url,
     };
  });
```

Comment: I made this and worked, thx :)